# changes are not reflected in laravel views

Tags: php, laravel, caching, view, laravel-5.1

I am creating an app in  Laravel 5.1 and it was working fine before. Any changes I made in the views files were reflected in the browser. Now for the last 3 days no change is reflected in the browser.

These are my view files:

**master.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- my head section goes here -->
<!-- my css and js goes here -->
<title></title>

{!!Html::style('css/bootstrap.min.css')!!}
{!!Html::style('css/main.css')!!}


{!!Html::script('js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js')!!}
{!!Html::script('js/bootstrap.min.js')!!}
{!!Html::script('js/jquery.validate.min.js')!!}
{!!Html::script('js/main.js')!!}

</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="container">@include('layout.header')</div>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="contents"> @yield('content') </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <div class="container">@include('layout.footer')</div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I am changing the name of the css file to app.css but when I run the app it shows main.css in source.

I looked for cache in storage/framework  it shows the view file with old code 'main.css' I deleted all the cache files, I also tried  ***php artisan cache:clear*** and ***php artisan view:clear*** but when I run the app it shows old html in source code and when I checked the cache files it regenerates cache file with old view code. I tried different change but nothing is reflected in the cache or browser.

Comment: You want to load `app.css` but your code above is still using `{!!Html::style('css/main.css')!!}`?

Comment: yes . i tried different changes like , deleting a div removing all html etc nothing is reflected

Comment: it is in the cache files where it is still using `{!!Html::style('css/main.css')!!}`. in the view files it changes are updated.

Comment: Do you use Cloudflare?

Comment: also can you show us your controller too?

Comment: this is the route `Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pages.home');
});` for homepage not using any controller

Comment: try to clear your browser cache of files

Answer (score 2):

Try the following commands, it might help

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

This commands worked for me!

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Thanks to this link :D ! 
[Link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/changing-blade-files-never-change-when-refreshingclearing-cache)